# Test fails due to objectproperties file can't be found

Tags: selenium, batch-file, testng

I've mobile automation test cases written in Selenium, Appium & TestNG.

Invoking test cases works fine when run from eclipse, but when I run the batch script by invoking testng.xml test fails as it's failing to find  object property file.

And fails with following error stack

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.streamW3CProtocolParameters(ProtocolHandshake.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at com.xyz.xya.LeadTest.Launchapplication(RetailKeywords.java:47)
    at com.xyz.xya.LeadTest.readData(RetailExecuteLead.java:111)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:527)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:167)
        ... 35 more
... Removed 27 stack
```

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ and the _error stack trace_

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven Surefire Plugin if you are relying on running your tests from terminal mode or batch mode. And also, make sure you mention your test resources inside the build tag of your pom.xml like so.

```
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

Now whenever you have to load your property file do so using an InputStream of some sorts. Or simply using the File class.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/object.properties");
```

What the above stuff does is, during the build, maven knows where to pick the resource file from. And since you have mentioned the resources in pom, you can directly get the file using classpath without using file-systems directly.

Comment: The project doesn't use any maven/ant./gradle. it's simple java project with TestNG and other necessary library files

Comment: I can put the directory structure, batch script and testng file but not source code @ DebanjanB.

Projectname

Comment: Use an absolute path to your properties file. Seems like relative path is not working. Check with absolute path and report back please.

Comment: D:\Projectname
 -settings
 -bin
 -lib
 -test-output
        -testng.xml
  --src
  -com
   -org
    -retailpos
     -constants
      -RetailConstants.java
     -retailobjectrepository
      -RetailObjectReposiyory.properties
     -retailtestcases
      -RetailTestData.xlxs
     -retailstestscript
      -Performance.java
      -RetailExecuteLead.java
      -RetailKeywords.java
      -test.bat

Comment: I'm using absolute path only @SteroidKing666

Comment: --Batch file--
set projectLocation=D:\Projectname
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin\;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java  org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml

Comment: --TestNG.xml--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.org.retailpos.retailtestscript.RetailExecuteLead"/>
   
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: You probably have multiple Guava related jar files. I suggest you check and get it down to a single Guava file. I am not sure about it but it seems like a conflict caused by multiple jars.

Comment: Great. So what was the problem? If any kind of answers help in this site please accept it so we can document it for others to gain from such discussions.

Answer (score 0):

@SteroidKing666 thanks a lot for the guidance.
As suspected by you it was due to conflict of multiple versions of Guava I had 17.0 & 21.0

I removed 17.0 and kept 21.0 version of it and then vooila it works.